# Signing ArcGIS Add-In with a post-build event

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, visual-studio

I'm attempting to automate signing of an ArcGIS Add-In using a post build event in visual studio that triggers a batch file (which subsequently triggers ESRISignAddIn utility). Running the batch file manually through command prompt works fine, the Add-In is signed successfully. However if I attempt to run the batch file in the post-build event, it returns an error saying the Add-In file cannot be found. I've noticed that by the time the build process gets to the post-build stage, only the DLLs are created - the Add-In file is not, hence the batch file cannot find it. It appears the Add-In file is created AFTER the post-build event (illogical, I know).

I have tried adding the batch commands to the post-build event command line (in project settings > compile > build events), and have also tried adding this directly to the project file XML:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)Post_Build.bat&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)my.esriAddIn&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Seems that 'post build' and 'after build' events are both executed before the esriaddin file is built, useless!

Has anyone had any experience working with post-build events and ArcGIS Add-Ins? **I want to know if it's possible to force the Add-In file (my.esriaddin) to be created before the post-build event.**

My last resort solution is to execute the build and then the batch file using a build runner (e.g. finalbuilder), but would ideally like to keep everything in the same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in that I needed to copy the add-in output file to another directory using a post-build event. Like you, I had a problem in that the add-in file hadn't been created by the time the post-build event fired.

I believe I may have a solution for you. Instead of the target you are using above, try this:

```
  <Target AfterTargets="RunArcGISPostPackageEvent" Name="SignMyAddin">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)Post_Build.bat&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)my.esriAddIn&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

For further clarity, in my .csproj file I have an import (presumably added by Esri) that says this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ESRI\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ESRI\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.targets')" />
```

If I open that imported file, there is a target in there with a name RunArcGISPostPackageEvent, which as far as I can tell is the last thing Esri is doing to finish up creating the *.addin file.  So using the AfterTargets attribute on a custom target will wait until after that other target is done before running.  If the above doesn't work, you might try `AfterTargets=PackageArcGISAddInContents` as that is another target in the imported project.

I'm not an expert so there may be a better way, but this has worked for me.

Comment: You are an absolute saviour. This solution works! Many thanks for your help, much appreciated.